# Animate accordion panels when hide and show a panel

Tags: css, animation, vuejs3, accordion, nuxtjs3

I have created an Accordion component in a Vue3 and Nuxt3 project. everything is good except that I can't put an animation on the height of accordion panels. I want a smooth remove when I hide a panel from this accordion.

here are the accordion panels:

```
const panels = [
    {id:1,title:'Test Accordion 1',icon:'',},
    {id:2,title:'Test Accordion 2',icon:'',},
    {id:3,title:'Test Accordion 3',icon:'',},
]
```

and where I use that component like:

```
<accordion :panels="panels">

    <template #1>
         this is one
    </template>
    <template #2>
        this is two
    </template>
    <template #3>
        this is three
    </template>

</accordion>
```

and this is the SFC file:

```
<script setup lang="ts">

const props = defineProps({
    panels: {type: Array,},
})

const current = ref(1)

function toggleAccardion(index: any) {
    if (current.value == index) {
        current.value = 0
        return
    }
    current.value = index
}
</script>
<template>

    <div v-for="panel in panels" :key="panel.id">

        <div class="d-flex flex-row p-4 cursor-pointer bg-gray-200" @click.prevent="toggleAccardion(panel.id)">
            <div v-if="panel.icon">
                {{ panel.icon }}
            </div>
            <div class="flex-grow-1">
                <h4 class="mb-0">{{ panel.title }}</h4>
            </div>
            <div>
                <i v-if="panel.id  === current" class="ki-outline ki-minus fs-4 text-gray-800"></i>
                <i v-else class="ki-outline ki-plus fs-4 text-gray-800"></i>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="p-4" v-if="panel.id  === current">
            <slot :name="panel.id"></slot>
        </div>

    </div>

</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<transition>` component which works as expected in this case. Look [here for more info](https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/transition.html#the-transition-component).

First of all, wrap your content (panel) with `<Transition>` component like this:

```
<Transition>
    <div class="p-4" v-if="panel.id  === current">
        <slot :name="panel.id"></slot>
    </div>
</Transition>
```

Set a name attribute for transition component: `<Transition name="accordion">`.
Now You can create custom animation with exact same name as name of `Transition`.

```
@keyframes accordion {
    0% {
        max-height: 0;
    }

    100% {
        max-height: 200px; // max possible value
    }
}

.accordion-enter-active {
    animation: accordion 0.2s linear;
}

.accordion-leave-active {
    animation: accordion 0.2s linear reverse;
}
```

Set max possible height of panel for `max-height`, because we can't animate with `height:auto` or percent value

Well, if You try this, it looks glitchy. Because there is also some padding for that panel. So we should add padding to that animation. Update `@keyframe` as following:

```
@keyframes accordion {
    0% {
        max-height: 0;
        padding: 0 16px; // horizontal padding should not be animated
    }

    100% {
        max-height: 200px;
        padding: 16px;
    }
}
```

**The more accurate the max-height, the smoother the animation.**